# XSLT - Remove child node while on appear in complete sentence

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input XML is like as shown below:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><para><emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Factor</emph></emph></para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para><emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Important examples</emph></emph></para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para><emph type="italic">Content</emph></para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para><emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Page</emph></emph></para></td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2"><para><emph type="bold">Viral infection with</emph> <emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Myxovirus influenzae</emph></emph></para></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Output should be

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><para>Factor</para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para>Important examples</para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para>Content</para></td>
    <td valign="top"><para>Page</para></td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2"><para><emph type="bold">Viral infection with</emph> <emph type="bold"><emph type="italic">Myxovirus influenzae</emph></emph></para></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

My XSLT is as shown below.

```
 <xsl:template match="emph">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::thead/tr/td/para">                
                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>                                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

While running above XSLT, it's removing all emphasis from para whether it's partial emphasized or fully. But, we should remove only fully emphasized node within sentence. If the sentence is emphasized partially then we should not make any change.

Comment: I am sorry, but what you mean by fully emphasized, i.e. why the para containing the text "Content" is not fully emphasized? As the desired output suggest?

Comment: If bold/italic is appearing for entire sentence within "para" then we should remove the same. If it's appear partially then we should keep as it is.

Comment: so the line `<td valign="top"><para><emph type="italic">Content</emph></para></td>` should be `<td valign="top"><para>Content</para></td>` in the desired output ?

Comment: Yes gtosto..Correct...

Comment: but your 3rd <td> has partial (which is italic) but u r removing emph. so I am not clear what u r doing?

Comment: Partial means sentence emphasizing(formatting) partially. It does not mean italic or bold. The conditions are: 1) If the entire sentence is fully bold or italic then we should remove styling/format. 2) If entire the sentence is styled as bold and italic then we should remove style/format. 3) If only specified words are bold or italic or both then we should keep as it.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para[emph[emph]]">
      <para>
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
      </para>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para[emph]">
      <para>
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
      </para>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para[emph[2]]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```